# Oscillator output is absent

Tags: proteus

I designed a oscillator circuit in proteus but oscilloscope not showing generated frequency of oscillator.As I am beginner in proteus it is bit difficult to understand the problem. Here is my circuit.
[image]

Comment: What supply voltage to the op-amp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that is likely to be problematic is that the minimum supply voltage in the data sheet is specified as 10V. If you are using the same supply as your previous question then 9V isn't enough to be able to rely on performance expectations in the DS.

Assuming you were running at 10V then the typical p-p output voltage would be able to reach about 8.5V and drop as lows as about 1.5V.

Now, if you read the DS you will get an idea about the usable input voltage range of the device - it's called "common-mode input voltage range" and on page 6 it guarantees +/- 11V on a +/-15 V supply - translate this to a +/- 5V supply and you get +/- 1V input range. It doesn't translate proportionally just in case you thought it might - it's subtractive.

So, on a +10V supply (and ground) the inputs must be constrained to within the range of +4V to +6V. This doesn't happen in your circuit - if the output was low, the voltage at the non-inverting input would be 3.0625V and outside the common mode range of the chip.

Short answer - if you are running at 9V then run at 10V and, if you are running at 10V then use less hysterisis (increase R11) and make the bias network (R8 and R9) symmetrical in order to use the best amount of input range allowed.

Comment: Sir I have implemented all the suggestions u siad, running at 10V instead of 9V, I even try to simulate the circuit at 15V. I increased the value of R11 and made the bias network symmetrical but still there is no change at the output side. @Andy

Comment: Have you tried doing a really long scan in the simulator to see if it eventually starts oscillating. I can only advise you on the misuse of the TL072 and what is said in the data sheet.

Comment: Another problem with the TL072 is that it probably doesn't have the bandwidth to achieve the high frequency you are expecting. Unity gain bandwidth is about 3 MHz and if you are expecting it to function correctly at frequencies higher than 300 kHz then forget it and choose a higher spec op-amp with rail-to-rail capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I substituted an opamp with the same unity-gain bandwidth as the TI part, and it runs just fine in LTspice:

[image]

BTW, Here's the LTspice circuit list just in case you want to play with the circuit:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE -496 0 -608 0
WIRE -272 0 -496 0
WIRE 304 0 -272 0
WIRE 528 0 304 0
WIRE -496 48 -496 0
WIRE -224 48 -400 48
WIRE -112 48 -144 48
WIRE -32 48 -112 48
WIRE 304 48 304 0
WIRE 576 48 400 48
WIRE 688 48 656 48
WIRE 752 48 688 48
WIRE -272 112 -272 0
WIRE 528 112 528 0
WIRE -400 128 -400 48
WIRE -288 128 -400 128
WIRE 400 128 400 48
WIRE 512 128 400 128
WIRE -112 144 -112 48
WIRE -112 144 -224 144
WIRE 688 144 688 48
WIRE 688 144 576 144
WIRE -496 160 -496 128
WIRE -320 160 -496 160
WIRE -288 160 -320 160
WIRE 304 160 304 128
WIRE 480 160 304 160
WIRE 512 160 480 160
WIRE -608 192 -608 0
WIRE -496 192 -496 160
WIRE 304 192 304 160
WIRE -400 208 -400 128
WIRE 400 208 400 128
WIRE -320 256 -320 160
WIRE -224 256 -320 256
WIRE -112 256 -112 144
WIRE -112 256 -144 256
WIRE 480 256 480 160
WIRE 576 256 480 256
WIRE 688 256 688 144
WIRE 688 256 656 256
WIRE -608 320 -608 272
WIRE -496 320 -496 272
WIRE -496 320 -608 320
WIRE -400 320 -400 272
WIRE -400 320 -496 320
WIRE -272 320 -272 176
WIRE -272 320 -400 320
WIRE 304 320 304 272
WIRE 304 320 -272 320
WIRE 400 320 400 272
WIRE 400 320 304 320
WIRE 528 320 528 176
WIRE 528 320 400 320
WIRE -608 384 -608 320
FLAG -608 384 0
FLAG -32 48 OUT1
FLAG 752 48 OUT2
SYMBOL res 288 32 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 288 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap 384 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 100p
SYMBOL res 672 32 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res 672 240 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 11k
SYMBOL res -512 32 R0
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res -512 176 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL cap -416 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 100p
SYMBOL res -128 32 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 10k
SYMBOL res -128 240 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 1k
SYMBOL voltage -608 176 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 12 0 500u)
SYMBOL Opamps\\LT1351 -256 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL Opamps\\LT1351 544 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
TEXT -594 352 Left 2 !.tran 1m
```

Comment: The big differences is the input common mode range of the LT1351 - on a 10V supply the input range is 1.4V to 8.6 volts and that's the problem with the TL072 on a 10V supply. Slew rate is also massively higher. +1 for a good sim anyway.